# 1120 undefined error, but the instance name is correct

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

There are 2 separate buttons, `a`, and `b`. I have double checked and triple checked that their instance name is a and b respectively.

I want a to take me to frame3, and b to frame4.

But when I test it, it tells me that it (both) is undefined so the buttons don't do anything.

Before that, I have a start menu and I have the same code for the 'Start' button and it works just fine, it takes me to the frame where a and b are.
But other buttons just won't work? I always get the same undefined error.

```
a.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, aClick);
function aClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
 gotoAndStop(3);
}
b.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, bClick);
function bClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
 gotoAndStop(4);
}
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please post your code where you create two buttons.

Comment: @Joe Taras  Thank you, but I have fixed the problem.Turns out, I had to untick advanced layers in the document.